# Replace Characters from string with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, string, replace

I have a string like (which is a shared path)

```
\\cnyc12p20005c\mkt$\\XYZ\
```

I need to replace all  `\\` with single slash so that I can display it in textbox. Since it's a shared path the starting `\\` should not be removed. All others can be removed.

How can I achieve this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expression to achieve this:

```
var s = '\\\\cnyc12p20005c\\mkt$\\\\XYZ\\';
console.log(s.replace(/.\\\\/g, '\\')); //will output \\cnyc12p20005c\mkt$\XYZ\
```

Double backslashes are used because backslash is special character and need to be escaped.

Comment: s.replace(/.\\/g, '/') gives \\\cnyc12p20005c\mkt$\\XYZ\

Comment: not `/.\\/g`, but `/.\\\\/g`. It was answer for your unedited question.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it like this:

```
var newStr = str.replace(/(.)\\{2}/, "$1\\");
```

Or this, if you don't like having boobs in your code:

```
var newStr = "\\" + str.split(/\\{1,2}/).join("\\");
```